# How to save the implementation in javascript in Django

Tags: javascript, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am implementing a page that represents the information of the selected option when I select the option in Django. The source code is written to adjust the quantity. The price has been implemented to change depending on the quantity. I want to save the quantity and price parts in the database. How to achieve that?

**html**

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'zeronine:join_create' id=product.product_code %}">
<div class="form-group row" style="margin-top: -5px">
    <label for="optionSelect" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label"><b>옵션</b></label>
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin-left: -90px;">
             <select type="text" class="form-control" name="value_code" id="optionSelect" value="{{ form.value_code }}">
                 <option value="none">옵션을 선택하세요.</option>
                    {% for option in option_object %}
                       {% if option.option_code.option_code.option_code == value.option_code %}
                           {%if option.product_code == product %}
                               <optgroup label="{{option.name}}">
                    {% for value in value_object %}
                       {% if value.option_code.option_code == option.option_code %}
                           {%if value.product_code == product %}
                                 <option data-price="{{value.extra_cost}}"value="{{value.value_code}}">{{value.name}} (+{{value.extra_cost}}원)</option>
                           {% endif %}
                       {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                           {% endif %}
                       {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                             </optgroup>
            </select>

        </div>
     <div id="selectOptionList" style="margin-top:10px; margin-left: 20px; margin-bottom: -10px;"></div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
<script>
$().ready(function() {
   $("#optionSelect").change(function() {
       var checkValue = $("#optionSelect").val();
       var checkText = $("#optionSelect option:selected").text();
       var product = $("#productname").text();
       var price = parseInt($("#price").text());
       var test = parseInt($(this).find(':selected').data('price'));
       var hapgae = price + test

       if (checkValue != "no") {
           var whtml =
               "            <div class=\"cart_table\">\n" +
               "            <hr style='width: 300px; margin-bottom: 30px;'>" +
               "            <p style='font-size: 17px;'>" + product + "</p>" +
                              "<p style='font-size: 13px; margin-top: -10px;  margin-bottom: 20px;'>" + checkText + "</p>" +
               "             <span class=\"del_li_btn\" style='float: right; margin-right: 30px;'><img src=\"https://tictoc-web.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/web/img/icon/btn_del_circle.svg\" style='width: 80%;'></span>\n" +
               "            <ul class=\"cart_list\">\n" +
               "                <li style='list-style:none; margin-left: -38px;'>\n" +
               "                    <div class=\"opt_info\">\n" +
               "                        <strong style='display: none' class=\"price_unit\">" + hapgae + "</strong>\n" +
               "                        <div class=\"price_btn\">\n" +
               "                            <input type=\"button\" value=\"-\" class=\"minus_btn\">\n" +
               "                            <input style='width: 15%;' type=\"text\" value=\"0\" class=\"number\">\n" +
               "                            <input type=\"button\" value=\"+\" class=\"plus_btn\">\n" +
               "                        </div>\n" +
               "                <div class=\"total_p\" style='margin-top:30px; margin-left: -2px;'>\n" +
               "                    <p style=\"font-size: 18px;\">가격<strong class=\"price_amount\" style=\"font-size: 18px; color: #849160; margin-left: 180px;\">" + 0 + "</strong>원\n" +
               "                </div>\n" +
               "                    </div>\n" +
               "                </li>\n" +
               "            </ul>" +
               "            </div>" +
               "\n" +
               "\n" +
               "        </div>"
           ;
           $("#selectOptionList").append(whtml)
       }

       $(document).ready(function () {
           $('.price_btn input[type="button"]').on('click', function () {
               var $ths = $(this);
               var $par = $ths.parent().parent();
               var $obj = $par.find('input[type="text"]');
               var val = $obj.val();
               if ($ths.val() == '-') {
                   if (val > 1)
                       $obj.val(--val);
               } else if ($ths.val() == '+') {
                   if (val < 30)
                       $obj.val(++val);
               }

               //수량 변경
               var unit_amount = $par.find('.price_unit').text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
               var quantity = val;
               pay_unit_func($par, unit_amount, quantity);
               pay_total_func();
           });

           function pay_unit_func($par, unit_amount, quantity) {
               //1번 단
               var unit_total_amount = $par.find('.price_amount').text((unit_amount * quantity).toLocaleString());
           }

           function pay_total_func() {
               //2번 단
               var amount_total = 0;
               var converse_unit = 0;
               $('.cart_list li').each(function () {
                   converse_unit = $(this).find('.price_amount').text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
                   amount_total = amount_total + (parseInt(converse_unit) || 0);
               });

               var total_amount_money = $('.cart_total_price').children().find('.item_price').text(amount_total.toLocaleString());
               var total_total_price = $('.cart_total_price').children().find('.total_price').text(total_price.toLocaleString());

           }

//개별 아이템 삭제
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.del_li_btn').on('click', function () {
        var recent_delete_cnt = $('.del_btn .num').text();
        var check_delete_ck = $(this).parent().find('div[class="price_btn"]');

        if (check_delete_ck == true) {
            recent_delete_cnt = recent_delete_cnt - 1;
            $('.del_btn .num').text(recent_delete_cnt);
        }

        $(this).parent().remove();
        pay_total_func();

            });
          });
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**forms.py**

```
class ElementForm(forms.Form):
    value_code = forms.ModelChoiceField(error_messages={'required': "옵션을 선택하세요."}, label="옵션", queryset=Value.objects.all())

class JoindetailForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.IntegerField(error_messages={'required': "1개 이상 선택 시 참여가 가능합니다."}, label="수량")
    price = forms.IntegerField(error_messages={'required': "1개 이상 선택 시 참여가 가능합니다."}, label="가격")
```

**views.py**

```
def join_create(request, id):
    current_category = None
    designated = Designated.objects.all()
    designated_object = Designated.objects.filter(rep_price='True')
    value_p = Value.extra_cost
    element = Element.objects.all()
    join_detail = JoinDetail.objects.all()
    value_object = Value.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.all()

    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('zeronine:login'))

    if request.method == "POST":
            product = Product.objects.get(product_code=id)
            join = Join()
            join.product_code = product
            join.username = request.user
            join.save()

            if request.method == "POST":
                form = ElementForm(request.POST)

                if form.is_valid():
                    element = Element()
                    element.designated_code = Designated.objects.get(product_code=id)
                    element.value_code = form.cleaned_data['value_code']
                    element.save()

                else:
                    element = Element()
                    element.designated_code = Designated.objects.get(product_code=id)
                    element.value_code = None
                    element.save()

                    if request.method == "POST":
                        form = JoindetailForm(request.POST)

                        if form.is_valid():
                            join_detail = JoinDetail()
                            join_detail.join_code = join
                            join_detail.designated_code = Designated.objects.get(product_code=id)
                            join_detail.price = form.cleaned_data['price']
                            join_detail.save()

                return render(request, 'zeronine/list.html', {'products': 'products',
                                                              'current_category': current_category,
                                                              'products': products,
                                                              'join_detail':join_detail,
                                                              'categories': categories,
                                                              'designated': designated})

            return render(request, 'zeronine/list.html', {'products':'products',
                                                          'current_category': current_category,
                                                          'products': products,
                                                          'join_detail':join_detail,
                                                          'categories': categories,
                                                          'designated': designated})


    return render(request, 'zeronine/detail.html', {'product':'product',
                                                    'designated': designated,
                                                    'element': element,
                                                    'join_detail':join_detail,
                                                    'value_p':value_p,
                                                    'designated_object':designated_object,
                                                    'value_object': value_object})
```

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='username')
    category_code = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='products')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=False, allow_unicode=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    benefit = models.TextField()
    detail = models.TextField()
    target_price = models.IntegerField()
    start_date = models.DateField()
    due_date = models.DateField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['product_code']
        index_together = [['product_code', 'slug']]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('zeronine:product_detail', args=[self.product_code, self.slug])

# 옵션(옵션코드, 옵션명, 상품코드(fk))
class Option(models.Model):
    option_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    product_code = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='product_code')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['option_code']

# 옵션값(옵션값코드, 옵션값명, 옵션코드(fk), 상품코드(fk))
class Value(models.Model):
    value_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    option_code = models.ForeignKey(Option, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='option_code')
    product_code = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='product_code')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    extra_cost = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['value_code']

# 옵션지정상품(옵션지정상품코드, 상품코드(fk), 가격, 참여수량)
class Designated(models.Model):
    designated_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product_code = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='product_code')
    price = models.IntegerField()
    rep_price = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['designated_code']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.designated_code)

# 상품옵션구성(상품옵션구성코드, 옵션지정상품코드, 옵션값코드)
class Element(models.Model):
    element_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    designated_code = models.ForeignKey(Designated, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='designated_code')
    value_code = models.ForeignKey(Value, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='value_code', null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['element_code']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.element_code)

# 참여(참여코드, 아이디(fk), 상품코드(fk), 수량)
class Join(models.Model):
    join_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='username')
    product_code = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='product_code')
    part_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.join_code)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['join_code']

#참여상세(참여상세코드, 수량, 가격, 참여코드, 옵션지정상품코드)
class JoinDetail(models.Model):
    joindetail_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    join_code = models.ForeignKey(Join, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='join_code')
    designated_code = models.ForeignKey(Designated, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, db_column='designated_code')
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.joindetail_code)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['joindetail_code']
```

Comment: it mean you what save JoindetailForm in JoinDetail?

Comment: @ming That's right. I'd like to save qantity and price in join_detail at views.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `request.POST.get('')` , because in your html, I don't see `JoindetailForm` so your `form = JoindetailForm(request.POST)` will Null value, you can try this:

you can add your `unit_amount * quantity` to input value and type is hidden:

```
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="">
```

in view use `request.POST.get('')` to get hidden value:

```
price = request.POST.get('price')
```

and use objects.create beter than Form():

```
JoinDetail.objects.create(price=price, quantity=quantity)
```

and you have to many `if request.method == "POST":` in first if is POST it `request.method` will be POST, so just leave first time will be good and easy to debug.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Quantity is implemented in the <div class=\"price_btn\" part of script, how can I save this part to db?

Comment: add the name in your <input type="button" value="" class="plus_btn" name>
use request.POST.get('name') and you can get value, use create to save this value to db